# How can I install ruby on rails in elementary os?

Tags: software-installation

I'm want to install ruby on rails, in elementary os, but every tutorial that I follow it comes with a issue of rvm or missing dependencies, do you guy know if I need to install before or if you know where can I find a guide to do it for elementary that will be great.

Just in case I erased ruby:

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems
```

Answer (score 1):

To install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev nodejs
```

Comment: Wait, Ruby depends on Nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guys.

I follow another install guide, I hope it help other people with the same issue, this is the link:

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04?
follow it step by step
the before installing ruby build environment use

For some reasons my Ubuntu platform were missing some dependencies and by forcing the following installation, it solve the prblem:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

In particular I got installed the following extra packages using sudo apt-get install:

```
automake autotools-dev g++ g++-4.8 libbison-dev libc6-dev libsigsegv2
  libssl-doc libstdc++-4.8-dev linux-libc-dev m4
```

as well as the following NEW packages:

```
autoconf automake autotools-dev bison build-essential g++ g++-4.8
  libbison-dev libc6-dev libsigsegv2 libssl-dev libssl-doc libstdc++-4.8-dev
  linux-libc-dev m4 zlib1g-dev
```

After installing all these dependencies install ruby using the steps given in the above link.
It worked for me.

Comment: I ran the first install, was missing sqlite3 so I followed the prompt to install, and that was all that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the you ubuntu version but try this one:

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-ruby-ubuntu